# Get difference of two address of array(use & operator)

Tags: c, arrays

I want to get the address difference between two elements in an array.

```
int vector[] = { 28, 41, 7 };

printf("%d\n", &vector[2]); // 1703652
printf("%d\n", &vector[1]); // 1703648
printf("%d\n", &vector);    // 1703644

printf("%d\n", &vector[1] - &vector); // 1
```

The result I expect(Last Line) is `4` because the data type was `int`.

Further, each result of address has `4` differences.

But why is the result of

```
&vector[1] - &vector
```

`1` and not `4`?

And how do I get `4` by using subtraction operator?

Comment: `printf("%d\n", &vector[2]);` is a type error. `%d` takes an `int`, not a memory address.

Comment: `&vector[1] - &vector` is a type error. The left operand of `-` has type `int *`, but the right operand has type `int (*)[3]` (they need to have the same type).

Comment: How does the last one even compi!e?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pointer arithmetics in C language works on the type of the object. It does not matter how big the object is. The reference to the next object minus reference to the previous is always **one** object

So if we add 5 to the pointer it will point 5 objects ahead. If we increment the pointer it will reference the next object. It helps indexing and iterating across the objects.

When you printf the address (your format is wrong - you should use %p instead) it is printed in bytes. So the difference between the consecutive objects will be equal the size of the object (plus the optional padding).

> And How to I get 4 by using subtraction operator???

Cast the pointers to the type which sizeof is one for example `char`.

```
(char *)&vector[1] - (char *)&vector
```

Answer (score 3):

You can calculate the difference of pointers to byte-sized values by casting the pointers to `char *`:

```
printf("%d\n", (char*)&vector[1] - (char*)vector);
```

Comment: Also, if you want to get the number of bytes that spans the address range, you add +1 to the above.